# Javascript function stopping other functions working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following Javascript functions. `Yes()` and `No()`. I want to add another function `Ex()`, but it won't let me? Yes() and No() just stop working when I add it, no matter where it's added in the code.
Can somebody please explain what's wrong? Thanks.

```
function no() {
    location.reload();
}
function yes() {
    document.getElementById('ex').innerHTML = "<button onclick="ex()">Test</button>;
}
function ex() {
    alert('test');

}
```

Comment: You should have this in the function yes `"<button onclick=\"ex()\">Test</button>";` You were missing the last quotation mark and escaping the inner ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

escape you " in the string.

```js
function no() {
    location.reload();
}
function yes() {
    document.getElementById('ex').innerHTML = "<button onclick=\"ex()\">Test</button>";
}
function ex() {
    alert('test');

}
yes();
```

```html
<div id="ex"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can change the outer quote with single quote for avoid escaping if you don't like one and keep the inner quote with double quote instead.

```
'<button onclick="ex()">Test</button>'
```